# How to join two tables with adding id of table?

Tags: python, dataframe, join, merge, concatenation

I have two tables:

```
name   value
a1      45
a2      77
b1      99
```

```
name   value
e1      11
f5      99
z9      99
```

I want to join them and add new column id showing from which table row is:

```
name   value   id 
a1      45     old
a2      77     old
b1      99     old
e1      11     new
f5      99     new
z9      99     new
```

How to do that?

Comment: I guess you're working with pandas? Please add the tag, the term dataframe is also used in other data packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `assign` and `append`:

```
>>> df1.assign(id="old").append(df2.assign(id="new")).reset_index(drop=True)
  name  value   id
0   a1     45  old
1   a2     77  old
2   b1     99  old
3   e1     11  new
4   f5     99  new
5   z9     99  new
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using `pd.concat`:

```py
df = (
    pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=["old", "new"], names=["id"])
    .droplevel(1)
    .reset_index()
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    id name  value
0  old   a1     45
1  old   a2     77
2  old   b1     99
3  new   e1     11
4  new   f5     99
5  new   z9     99
```